# Asymptote graphics opacity in draw and filldraw gives undefined -21

Tags: asymptote

In implementing graphics output to Asymptote for [Mathics](https://mathics.org), I am running into problems in trying to use "opacity" in either asymptote's filldraw() or draw() commands.

Here is an example:

```
$ asy
Welcome to Asymptote version 2.62 (to view the manual, type help)
 filldraw((18.182,231.63)--(36.364,233.73)--(54.545,208.86)--(72.727,163.12)--(90.909,107.71)--(109.09,56.188)--(127.27,21.173)--(145.45,11.237)--(163.64,28.813)--(181.82,69.599)--(200,123.61)--(18.182,123.61)--cycle, rgb(0.2472, 0.24, 0.6)+opacity(0.2), nullpen);
> undefined -21
undefined -21
undefined -21
undefined -21
```

If I remove the "opacity parameter" that is:

```
filldraw((18.182,231.63)--(36.364,233.73)--(54.545,208.86)--(72.727,163.12)--(90.909,107.71)--(109.09,56.188)--(127.27,21.173)--(145.45,11.237)--(163.64,28.813)--(181.82,69.599)--(200,123.61)--(18.182,123.61)--cycle, rgb(0.2472, 0.24, 0.6), nullpen);
```

[image: Asymptote filled sine wave]

Comment: The code works well on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

Comment: @BlackMild Thanks - I am using the version on Ubunto 20.4 which happens to be 2.6.2-1.  It looks like I need to upgrade to 2.71-93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @BlackMild, I wasn't using a new enough version. I was running the release from Ubuntu 20.4 which is 2.62-1 while the version at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ is 2.71.93

Note that 2.71.93 is from this year, (2021) which means the code at that site is very new. 2.62 is circa 2019.

Also note that there seems to have been an number of [asymptote opacity problems reported (and fixed)](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20transparency).

And finally, after getting a new enough Asymptote, I found I needed a newer ghostscript. 9.50 was too old. 9.54.0 is fine though.

So with this,the [Mathics reference for release 4.0.0](https://mathics.org/docs/mathics-4.0.0.pdf) (at page 108) has a couple more graphs than were not there before.